# Why fread (PHP) don't read entire file?

Tags: php

I have this code on PHP that load a local file:

```
$filename = "fille.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "rb");
$content = fread($fp, 25699);
fclose($fp);
print_r($content);
```

With this code I can see all the contents of the file. But when I change the $filename to a external link, like:

```
$filename = "https:/.../texts/fille.txt";
```

I can't see all the contents of the file, he appears cut to me. Whats the problem?

Comment: Look at what parameter 2 of `fread` does, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php. I presume your local file is less than `25699` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The `fread()` function can be used for network operations. But network connections work different than file system operations. A network cannot read a bigger file in a single attempt, that is not how typical networks work. Instead they work package based. So data arrives in chunks.

And if you take a look into the documentation of the function you use then you will see that:

> Reading stops as soon as one of the following conditions is met:
>
> - [...]
> - a packet becomes available or the socket timeout occurs (for network streams)
> - [...]

So what you observe actually is documented behavior. You need to continue to read packages in a loop to get the whole file. Until you received an `EOF`.

Take a look yourself: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

And further down in that documentation you will see that example:

Example #3 Remote fread() examples

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "rb");
if (FALSE === $handle) {
    exit("Failed to open stream to URL");
}

$contents = '';

while (!feof($handle)) {
    $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```